# Wrong result when annotating with foreign key set filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

Model C has a foreign key link to model B. Model B has a foreign key link to model A. This is, model A instance may have many model B instances, and Model B may have many model C instances.

Pseudo-code:

```
class A:
    ...

class B:
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, ...)

class C:
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, ...)
```

I would like to retrieve the entire list of elements of model A from the database, annotating it with the count of B elements it has, where their respective count of C elements is not none (or any random number, for that matter).

I tried this:

```
A.objects.annotate(
    at_least_one_count=Count('b', filter=Q(b__c__isnull=False))
)
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should be working. However, numbers returned are not correct (in a practical case). It returns a higher number than without  the filter, which is obviously not possible:

```
A.objects.annotate(
    at_least_one_count=Count('b')
)
```

Edit: when I run the following query individually for every A instance, I get the same numbers, which makes me think there might be something wrong in my code:

```
A.objects.first().b_set.filter(c__isnull=False).__len__()
```

Note: I would like to perform this query without SQL. If I have to utilise some more advance Pythonic tools that Django provides, I am happy to do it, as long as I stay Object-Oriented. I am trying to move away from using raw SQL for all database operations, and re-write them all with Django ORM. However, it seems to be overly complicated.

Comment: it looks like the first query is just returning the count of all C elements with a B

Comment: Stupid mistake,  leaving the question for  if anyone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is simple: after applying queries that translate to join statements, one must execute a distinct on filter, which in Django is done by calling  `.distinct(...)` on the query set.**

In this case, if you are using a filter, and the distinct restriction is on the filter object, then you want to use:

```
...=Count('b', filter=Q(b__c__isnull=False), distinct=True)
```

Comment: Would `Count('b', filter=Q(b__c__isnull=False), distinct=True)` not do the trick?

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up using, I will add it in the answer.  Thank you for pointing out. @dirkgroten